# React npm ERR! Failed at the proyect-name@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux

acabo de crear un nuevo proyeto en react con `create-react-app`

luego instale algunas dependencias basicamente de r**edux, react-router, axios**, primero me equivoque de carpeta y las instale fuera de la carpeta del proyecto.. para probar copie estas carpetas de instalacion y sobreescribi en mi carpeta de instalacion.. (este puede ser la raiz del problema) al no funcionarme instale correctamente las dependencias en el directorio y ahora cuando ejecuto el comando `npm start`, pasa esto.. otra cosa estaba probando cosas hice la instalacion con npm i --save depedencia en vez de npm install --save dependencias
me muestra este error:

```
"react-scripts" it is not recognized as an internal or external command,
an executable program or a batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! proyecto-personas@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the proyecto-personas@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-02T13_20_21_728Z-debug.log
```

este es el .log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~prestart: proyecto-personas@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: proyecto-personas@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Israel\Documents\Studio\React\Cursos Udemy\4 proyectos con React Js\proyecto-personas\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;c:\sviluppo\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Novell\GroupWise;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\bin;;C:\Users\GONISR\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Israel\Documents\Studio\React\proyecto-personas
10 silly lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle proyecto-personas@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: proyecto-personas@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid proyecto-personas@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Israel\Documents\Studio\proyecto-personas
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error proyecto-personas@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the proyecto-personas@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

pudiera instalar todo de nuevo porque es un proyecto nuevo pero me gustaria saber porque me ocurrio esto en este proyecto y como se soluciona.. gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Puedes describir los pasos que te han llevado al error con más detalle y mostrar el contenido de `2019-09-02T13_20_21_728Z-debug.log`, por favor?

Comment: claro @AdolfoOnrubia lo subo... edito la pregunta

Comment: Prueba usando `npm i -g react-scripts`

Comment: @AlterLagos si me funciono...pero luego me muestra este error.. /node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users.\Documents..\node_modules\react-redux\es\components'

Comment: siguiendo luego los pasos de la respuesta de esta pregunta de este error resolvi el problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740483/module-not-found-cant-resolve-react...  basicamente lo q hice fue eliminar el package-lock.json la carpeta node_modules y hacer npm install.. no se si haciendo esto desde un principio hubiera servido.. pero funciono..

Answer (score 1):

El problema es más común de lo que parece, muchas veces ocurre que instalas alguna dependencia en una rama y cuando cambias a otra no las tienes disponibles por ejemplo.

Se soluciona como bien comentas en tu comentario de la siguiente manera, desde la raiz del proyecto

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm i
```

Con esto eliminas por completo la carpeta e instalas todas las dependencias nuevamente, creo que es la solución en el 99% de los casos.